# Dataplicity Remote Desktop (Wormhole)

Tags: remote

I am developing photo frames for presents to give to family members.  I am intrigued by the features of Dataplicity.  I have successfully configured the command-line access and the Wormhole access.  I have a couple of questions, however.

1. It seems wormhole access is using a virtual desktop.  Is there a way to use this service to view the actual desktop of the pi?  Ideally, I would like for my movements/actions on the desktop client to be reflected on the server side a la teamviewer.
2. Is there a way to launch applications from the Dataplicity command line interface that will run on the actual desktop gui of the pi?

Please forgive my novice questions, I am working to understand the differences between these services and any help is appreciated.